# Relational operators for floating point values in Unix Shell Scripting

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I'm writing a shell script to find out if any process is taking too much CPU utilization, then the script will send out a mail to the support team.

I have threshold limit as 25, and taking CPU Usage as:

```
cpuUsage=`ps -eo pcpu,pid,args | sort -k 1 -nr  | head -1`
```

Iterating over it to find out cpuUsage

```
for count in $cpuUsage
do
      CPUusageCount=$count
done
```

Then Checking `CPUUsageCount` with threshold limit as like this:

```
if [ $CPUusageCount -gt $THRESHOLD_LIMIT ];
then 
 #Sending mail to Support group
fi
```

Here I'm facing an error message: `Integer expression expected at  if [ $CPUusageCount`. Can't we use `-gt` to validate floating point numbers? Please help me how to achieve it?

Comment: See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could decide to chop the fractional part off the number, and then use `-ge` to compare:

```
if [ "${CPUusageCount%.*}" -ge $THRESHOLD_LIMIT ]
then
    # Send email
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `command-substitution` to compare two floating-point number.

#### example:

```
CPUusageCount=99.99
THRESHOLD_LIMIT=55.55

if [ `python -c "print $CPUusageCount>$THRESHOLD_LIMIT"` == 'True' ]; then
    echo Sending mail to Support group
fi
```

Comment: Very inefficient spawning of an external process.

Comment: @Barry: Do you have a solution that does floating-point comparison and *doesn't* spawn another process? Scripting very often involves external processes, anyways - and if it's a one-time thing, it doesn't really matter much anyway.

Comment: If you use an external process, it's much better to check the return value rather than comparing the output.  eg, if expr $CPUusage \> $THRESHOLD_LIMIT > /dev/null; then ...

Comment: Fixed point math.  Scale up by the desired precision multiplier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bc command:

```
if [ $(echo "$CPUusageCount >= $THRESHOLD_LIMIT"|bc) -eq 1 ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Floating point arithmetic is supported by ksh

```
#!/bin/ksh -x

CPUusageCount=99.99
THRESHOLD_LIMIT=55.55

if [ $CPUusageCount -gt $THRESHOLD_LIMIT ]; then
  echo Sending mail to Support group
fi
```

gives

```
+ CPUusageCount=99.99
+ THRESHOLD_LIMIT=55.55
+ [ 99.99 -gt 55.55 ]
+ echo Sending mail to Support group
Sending mail to Support group
```